# Parsing comment with antlr

Tags: c, parsing, comments, antlr

I'm using ANTLR to parse a custom data definition language. I'm using C as language and I'm outputting an abstract syntax tree. So far so good, but now I need to add documentation and I need to allow blocks of the form:

```
DOC
Free text here
ENDDOC
```

I tried adding a rule:

```
docstm  :   'DOC' ContentDoc=(.*) 'ENDDOC' -> ^(T_DOCCLASS $ContentDoc);
```

where `T_DOCCLASS` is an imaginary token defined in the section `tokens {...}`. Unfortunately, while the parsing does of a `DOC ... ENDDOC` block does not fail, the tree has only the `T_DOCCLASS` without any child node.

Other additional info: I'm using ANTLR 3.2 and the following prelude:

```
options {   
output   = AST;
language = C;
ASTLabelType = pANTLR3_BASE_TREE;
}
```

and I also have another rule for skipping withespaces:

```
WS  :   ( ' '
    | '\t'
    | '\r'
    | '\n'
    ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
;
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion you can give me.

Comment: What is the question? Try to terminate at least one sentence with a question mark.

Comment: @ceving, although there's no actual question mark, it's clear what the OP is trying to do (at least, it's clear if you've a bit knowledge of ANTLR, that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `.*` (zero or more tokens, in parser rules!), it's safer to do `(~ENDDOC)*` (zero or more tokens other than `ENDDOC`):

```
docstm      : DOC innerDocstm ENDDOC -> ^(T_DOCCLASS innerDocstm); 
innerDocstm : (~ENDDOC)*;
DOC         : 'DOC';
ENDDOC      : 'ENDDOC';
ID          : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
WS          : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

resulting in:

[image]

As you can see, there are no spaces inside the `T_DOCCLASS` AST. If you want to preserve spaces, you'll need to put the rule in the lexer:

```
DOCSTM : 'DOC' .* 'ENDDOC';
```

*(you must use `.*` now)*

Comment: Thank you very much, seeing other antlr questions here on SO, I suspected you could be very useful :-)